# Heuristic for Sudoku Cube

Tags: algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence, sudoku, heuristics

What would be a good heuristic for Sudoku Cube(3x3) ?
For Rubik's Cube where you have colours, heuristic can be decided easily but in Sudoku Cube where there is no idea what number is going to set up for which side, What is a good heuristic that can be used ?